# How does one pre-populate a Python Formish form?

Tags: python, formish

How does one pre-populate a [Formish](http://ish.io/projects/show/formish) form? The obvious method as per the documentation doesn't seem right. Using one of the provided examples:

```
import formish, schemaish
structure = schemaish.Structure()
structure.add( 'a', schemaish.String() )
structure.add( 'b', schemaish.Integer() )
schema = schemaish.Structure()
schema.add( 'myStruct', structure )
form = formish.Form(schema, 'form')
```

If we pass this a valid request object:

```
form.validate(request)
```

The output is a structure like this:

```
{'myStruct': {'a': 'value', 'b': 0 }}
```

However, pre-populating the form using `defaults` requires this:

```
form.defaults = {'myStruct.a': 'value', 'myStruct.b': 0}
```

The `dottedish` package has a `DottedDict` object that can convert a nested dict to a dotted dict, but this asymmetry doesn't seem right. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, don't require to use dotted dict, you can  easily use the post-validate style dict to pre-populate the form:

```
form.defaults={'myStruct': {'a': None, 'b': 'default_value'}}
```

maybe have old version of formish, try update the libs.